# Displaying a D3.js example in a webbrowser (noob question)

Tags: javascript

If i want to display the map you can see here : https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoom-to-bounding-box
in chrome for example, how do i get that work?
I tried copying the source code you can see below the map into the standard html format (in body) but it only showed the source code in chrome or nothing at all.

I apologize for such a noob question but if you could help me i would appreciate it!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64928268-fetch-12fxi?file=/src/index.js

Firstly you need to import the modules/files at the bottom of that page
[image]

Not forgetting the JSON data from this repository: https://github.com/topojson/us-atlas

To do this I suggest building your page with npm and maybe parcel or webpack. To do that you could create the file `package.json` in a new directory. Make sure you have nodejs and npm installed on your machine then:

1. From console type `npm install`
2. Afterwards type `npm run start` to run locally.
3. Or `npm run build` to package the application to upload online

**./package.json**

```
{
  "name": "vanilla",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "StackOverflow",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html --open",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "d3": "6.2.0",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "topojson-client": "3.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.2.0",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.6.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "javascript",
    "starter"
  ]
}
```

**./index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Stack Overflow</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I then found it useful to define chart as a function.

**./src/index.js**

```
const topojson = require("topojson-client");
const d3 = require("d3");
const path = d3.geoPath();

const getMapData = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/us-atlas@3/states-albers-10m.json"
  ).then((response) => response.json());
  return response;
};


const buildAndDisplayChart = async (domElement) => {
  const width = 975;
  const height = 610;
  const us = await getMapData()
  const zoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoomed);

  const svg = d3
    .create("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, height])
    .on("click", reset);

  const g = svg.append("g");

  const states = g
    .append("g")
    .attr("fill", "#444")
    .attr("cursor", "pointer")
    .selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
    .join("path")
    .on("click", clicked)
    .attr("d", path);

  states.append("title").text((d) => d.properties.name);

  g.append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
    .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, (a, b) => a !== b)));

  svg.call(zoom);

  function reset() {
    states.transition().style("fill", null);
    svg
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(
        zoom.transform,
        d3.zoomIdentity,
        d3.zoomTransform(svg.node()).invert([width / 2, height / 2])
      );
  }

  function clicked(event, d) {
    const [[x0, y0], [x1, y1]] = path.bounds(d);
    event.stopPropagation();
    states.transition().style("fill", null);
    d3.select(this).transition().style("fill", "red");
    svg
      .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .call(
        zoom.transform,
        d3.zoomIdentity
          .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
          .scale(
            Math.min(8, 0.9 / Math.max((x1 - x0) / width, (y1 - y0) / height))
          )
          .translate(-(x0 + x1) / 2, -(y0 + y1) / 2),
        d3.pointer(event, svg.node())
      );
  }

  function zoomed(event) {
    const { transform } = event;
    g.attr("transform", transform);
    g.attr("stroke-width", 1 / transform.k);
  }

  document.querySelector(domElement).appendChild(svg.node())
};

buildAndDisplayChart("body")
```

The function will generate an SVG which you can then append to your DOM element of choice.

Your final directory listing should be as follows :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a great answer!